# FlutterToast won't appear every time the button is clicked and throws an error

Tags: flutter, android-toast

I'm trying to call FlutterToast when I tap on InkWell widget. But whenever I try to tap, the FlutterToast won't show up. This is my Inkwell code.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () async {
    await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(
            text: controller.vaNumber.toString()));
    await Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        textColor: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 16.0
    );
  },
  child: Text(
    'SALIN',
    style: TextStyle(
        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
        color: Colors.green),
  ),
)
```

and this is my error message:

```
E/flutter (23418): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference, null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
E/flutter (23418):  at io.github.ponnamkarthik.toast.fluttertoast.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt:51)
E/flutter (23418):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/flutter (23418):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/flutter (23418):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/flutter (23418):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (23418):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/flutter (23418):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/flutter (23418):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/flutter (23418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/flutter (23418):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (23418):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/flutter (23418):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/flutter (23418): )
E/flutter (23418): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter (23418): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296:18)
E/flutter (23418): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23418): #2      Fluttertoast.showToast (package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart:101:17)
E/flutter (23418): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23418): #3      ReviewFundingView.build.<anonymous closure> (package:temanqu_member/app/modules/funding/review_funding/views/review_funding_view2.dart:228:31)
E/flutter (23418): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I've tried adding await and increasing/decreasing the FlutterToast library version but nothing changes. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm not so sure it has to do with `flutter_toast`. Would you share your `pubspec.yaml` to show us what dependencies your using?